# How do I split an output file into multiple blocks based on a pattern

Tags: perl

I  have an output file with the following content. I want to split it into blocks based on "pattern" and store in a array.

```
Sample output:
100 pattern
line 1
line 2
line 3
101 pattern
line 4
102 pattern   
line 5
line 6
 ...
```

Content between *n*<sup>th</sup> and (*n*+1)<sup>th</sup> occurrence of "pattern" is a block:

```
Block 1:
100 pattern
line 1
line 2
line 3

Block 2:
101 pattern
line 4


Block 3:
102 pattern   
line 5
line 6
```

Basically I am searching for a pattern across lines and storing the content in between into an array.

Please let me know how do I achieve in perl

Comment: Read in the file into an array. `join` the contents of the array into a single string, and then `split` on your pattern.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the patterns are 1-line-based? and do you want a block to be an element of the array or elements should be lines? and what is the nature of your pattern?

Comment: What have you done so far? What exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: done this work yesterday, just write an algorithm. :) `while($line !~(/\d+ pattern/)){  read_in_array();}` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your *pattern* are full lines containg the word `pattern` (and normal lines do not) and you want array elements to be entire blocks:

```
my @array;
my $i = 0;

for my $line ( <DATA> ) {
    $i++ if ( $line =~ /pattern/ );
    $array[$i] .= $line;
}

shift @array unless defined $array[0];  # if the first line matched the pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have accepted an answer, but I wanted to show how you might do it by reading in the data and using a regular expression to split it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;

my $input = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @input = split /(?=\d+ pattern)/, $input;

foreach (0 .. $#input) {
  say "Record $_ is: $input[$_]";
}

__DATA__
100 pattern
line 1
line 2
line 3
101 pattern
line 4
102 pattern   
line 5
line 6
```